# Using .htaccess file for good looking urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

What I'm trying to do is make my website's urls look prettier to the users.
For example I have this link in the **index.php** file in **a href** tags:

> index.php?v=class&id=5

And I want the user to see in the address bar this:

> www.mysite.com/class/5

I have tried using this code:

> RewriteRule /([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1&id=$2

But I found out that it does the opposite. It makes the good looking urls turn into bad ones. It would take the *www.mysite.com/class/5* and show this: *www.mysite.com/index.php?v=class&id=5*. What should I do?

Comment: Most frameworks (fuelphp, codeigniter) will do this for you. Try google next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.

Don't use `R` in your RewriteRule. R is an external redirect (it tells the browser to redirect, so the URL changes). Instead, remove the R to do an internal redirect, that way Apache can still parse the query string normally, but the user sees the pretty URL (the URL doesn't change in the browser).

Comment: `RewriteRule /([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1&id=$2 [L]` for example

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these yet?

Here's some links I found when seraching Google:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

http://www.nouveller.com/quick-tips/quick-tip-6-how-to-write-clever-pretty-urls-with-htaccess/